# Which private key using for CSR generated by TPM2?

Tags: pkcs#11, tpm

I'm following guidline to generate CSR: https://github.com/irtimmer/tpm2-pk11/wiki

After get certificate which signed by server side, in my case, I have to use private key used for CSR generation to handshake with SSL connection with server. I tried to convert `key.priv` using `base64` command but failed.
And my questions:

1) Can I use private key "key.priv" when created private key in TPM. If not which private key will be accepted?

```
tpm2_create -c po.ctx -g sha256 -G rsa -u key.pub -r key.priv
```

2) What are key.pub and key.priv used for?

Thank you very much.